# Change hostname in AWS OpsWorks (Chef)

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, hostname, aws-opsworks

In AWS OpsWorks, I'm using this community [hostname](https://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/hostname) cookbook. To set my hostname to append a domain to it.

Original FQDN: **apple-pie.localdomain**

```
node.default["set_fqdn"] = "*.example.com"
include_recipe 'hostname'
```

Changes to FQDN: **apple-pie.localdomain.example.com**

However, after about 10 mins, the hostname goes back to the original hostname without my domain append.

I've checked the OpsWorks lifecycle:

> After a new instance finishes booting, AWS OpsWorks does the
>   following:
>
> 1. Runs the built-in Setup recipes.
> 2. Runs any custom Setup recipes.
> 3. Runs the built-in Deploy recipes.
> 4. Runs any custom Deploy recipes.

And I'm running the recipe in my custom Deploy recipe, so it should be the last thing that runs. No idea why/how it gets reset to the original hostname.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like Amazon is changing the hostname...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. You're suppose to override the default template in Chef that AWS provides.

[Extending AWS OpsWorks Configuration Files Using Custom Templates](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-template-override.html)

So in my cookbook, I made a file called:

> opsworks_stack_state_sync/templates/default/hosts.erb

Add the file looks like this:

```
# This file was generated by OpsWorks
# any manual changes will be removed on the next update.

# Set the hostname with proper format, the rest are aliases.
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.example.com
127.0.1.1 <%= node[:opsworks][:instance][:hostname] %>.example.com <%= node[:opsworks][:instance][:hostname] %>

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts

# OpsWorks Layer State
<% seen = [] -%>
<% node[:opsworks][:layers].each do |layer_name, layer_config| -%>
<% layer_config[:instances].each do |instance_name, instance_config| -%>
<% if !seen.include?(instance_name) && instance_config[:private_ip] -%>
<%= Resolv.getaddress(instance_config[:private_ip]) %> <%= instance_name %>
<% if instance_config[:ip] %>
<%= Resolv.getaddress(instance_config[:ip]) %> <%= instance_name %>-ext
<% end %>
<% seen << instance_name %>
<% end -%>
<% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

And that will set your hostname to **apple-pie.example.com**.